# Is setting the useState to it's default value in the useEffect return hook necessary?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let's say I've got the following code, it has a useState hook which has a default value of an empty array:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default () => {
  const [fooData, setFooData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // some data fetching from and API happens here... example: setFooData(data);

    // this is what I am talking about
    return () => setFooData([]);
  }, []);
}
```

So basically what this does, is it fetches the data, sets that to the state and clears it again on unmount, but is that `return () => setFooData([])` necessary? Do I even need to clear the data on unmount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely do not need to set the state to initial state on unmount of the component.

The cleanup function is provided to remove listeners or subscriptions.

You state references are cleared and garbage collected on unmount. When the component mounts again the state is initialized again.

Comment: ah, so I was basically doing the cleanup myself?

Comment: setting the state to initialValue will not make a difference, its just an extra step that will happen

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary.

Just fetch, the data and put this into Your state. There is no need to worry about cleaning the state in that case

Answer (score 0):

the react useEffect hook has a clean up callback funtion that's available to clean your state.

```
useEffect(() => {

// Specify how to clean up after this effect:
return function cleanup() {
 // clean up code 
}; });
```